# Rails how to link to show action when using friendly_url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I link to show action with friendly_id ?

My view (does not work):

```
<% @konkurrencer.each do |vind| %>
<%= link_to 'vind.name', vind_path %>
<% end %>
```

My route file:

```
resources :konkurrencer, :controller => 'konkurrancers'
match '/:id' => 'kategoris#show'
```

I want my route to be :kategoris/:konkurrancer_name

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do this in english because I don't quite understand the pluralizations of vind and konkurrencer or how they relate etc... Hopefully you can modify it to yourself after:

```
<% @competitions.each do |competition| -%>
  <%= link_to competition.name, competition_category_path(competition.category, competition)
<% end -%>
```

Routes file:

```
# This gives you the route /category/:id
resource :category do
  # :controller => 'competitions' is implied
  resources :competitions
end
```

Now in your competitions model:

```
class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  def to_param
    self.name
  end
end
```

And in your category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competitions

  def to_param
    self.name
  end
end
```

The to_param method tells rails to use that value any time you send the object to a url helper method.  So in our view when we did `link_to competition.name, competition_category_path(competition.category, competition)` we were telling rails to use the non-id versions to generate the urls.

Make sure in your controller that you are getting the stuff out of the database like this:

```
class CompetitionsController
  def show
    @competition = Competition.find_by_name!(params[:id])
    @category = Category.find_by_name!(params[:category_id])
  end
end
```

Let me know if this helps :)  Sorry I changed it to english I hope I was still posting relevant code.

Comment: I dont need create update delete action. Can I do match ':kategoris/:id' => 'konkurrancers#show'?

Comment: You can add the :only => [:show] option to any of the resources calls.  So you could change it to `resources :competitions, :only => [:show]`, or the other one `resource :category, :only => [:show]` I think would also work.